# Twitter Service Proxy in C#

Tags: c#, rest, twitter

Does anyone know of a Twitter service proxy in particular, or a general-purpose REST service proxy that I could install on my own server, written in C#?

The point here is to direct Twitter service queries to my service that are passed-through to Twitter.

Comment: I don't use Twitter myself, but I did notice a recent CodeProject article by Pete O'Hanlon, one of CP's best authors on a Twitter Client http://www.codeproject.com/KB/smart/SongBird.aspx that mentions "REST." best,

Comment: Twitter has an API, which includes REST web methods also. Why can't you directly use it? Are you looking for a wrapper around it? 

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-API-Documentation

Comment: I'm looking to beat a firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be very simple with an ASP.NET MVC application.  I'm using a ControllerAction that accepts a POST and the URL to request as a parameter.  A jQuery `$.ajax()` call sends the request to the Action.  The ControllerAction opens a WebRequest to the URL passed in the POST, and forwards the result back to the client using `Content()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this project on codeplex [LNQ to Twitter](http://www.codeplex.com/LinqToTwitter), it might be of some help.

Comment: I've downloaded that, it's great but it's not what I need.  I need to be able to point Twitter queries to *my* service, and have them passed on to Twitter, then returned back through the same way.  Proxy.